# Create file expanding one variable but not another

Tags: shell-script, cat

I want to create a file from a bash script. But I need to expand some variables and print others literally is this possible?

```
cat <<EOF >  file.sh
$EXPAND
$PRINTLITERALLY
EOF
```

Also I'm trying to create a very big file, when I try to paste it in my terminal to test I get errors like:

```
-bash: urlencode: command not found
```

So it seems I may have stuff there that the bash is interpreting, will that affect my bash script when running it? I feel like there must be a better way to create files from my bash scripts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
EXPAND=value
cat <<EOF >  file.sh
$EXPAND
\$PRINTLITERALLY
EOF
```

would create `file.sh` with

```
value
$PRINTLITERALLY
```

as contents.

(you'd need to add a backslash before each occurrence of `$` or `` ` `` where you don't want the corresponding parameter expansion, arithmetic expansion or command substitution to be expanded. And you'd also need to escape some backslash characters as well).

Another approach:

```
cat - << EXPANDED /dev/fd/3 3<< 'NOT-EXPANDED' /dev/fd/4 4<< EXPANDED-AGAIN > file.sh
$EXPAND
`echo test`
...
EXPANDED
$PRINTLITERALLY
`echo test`
...
NOT-EXPANDED
$EXPAND
...
EXPANDED-AGAIN
```

The here documents where the delimiter is quoted (as in `3<< 'NOT-EXPANDED'` above) don't undergo shell expansions, so you can decide of sections where expansions are performed and some where they're not.

With the above, you'd get:

```
value
test
...
$PRINTLITERALLY
`echo test`
...
value
...
```

If you wanted to expand just one specific set of variables wherever they appear leaving all the other parameter expansions, command substitutions, arithmetic expansions unexpanded, you could use the `envsubst` utility shipped with GNU `gettext`.

Note however that it only expands `$var` and `${var}`, not any other form of parameter expansion involving the `$var` variable (like `${var#?}`, `${var[x]}`...)

```
EXPAND=value EXPAND_AS_WELL=othervalue
export EXPAND EXPAND_AS_WELL
envsubst '$EXPAND$EXPAND_AS_WELL' << '__end_of_envsubst__' > file.sh
$EXPAND ${EXPAND} ${EXPAND#?} ${EXPAND[0]} $EXPAND[0] $EXPANDÉ \$EXPAND
$PRINTLITERALLY $EXPAND_AS_WELL
`echo test`
__end_of_envsubst__
```

gives:

```
value value ${EXPAND#?} ${EXPAND[0]} value[0] valueÉ \value
$PRINTLITERALLY othervalue
`echo test`
```

See `info gettext envsubst` for further details.

Comment: Thanks. How do you handle stuff in the text that might be interpreted by the shell? It's a big and somewhat complex script... if there is a way to do the inverse it would be easier too...expand 1 variable only, rest print literally

Comment: I still can't create a correct file. Bash is executing and interpreting stuff inside my bash script. I'm using a bash script to write another bash script. Which has commands like $(command), functions... example () {commands}, variables, etc... must be there a easier and fastest way to create a file like that

Comment: @Freedo, see edit.

Comment: Thanks! That kept my terminal quiet :) what if you want to add another variable to envsubst? I need $user and $password

Comment: @Freedo, see edit

Comment: Actually my variables are not being replaced after all... `envsubst '$user$password' << '__end_of_envsubst__' >` creates a file where $user and $password are empty, and use bash -x to execute the script and I can see the variables are not empty before the envsubst run

Comment: @Freedo, they need to be exported to the environment (with `export`) for the `envsubst` external utility to have access to them.

Comment: that fixed it thanks!